# is it possible to http2 without the http1/1 initial call?

Tags: react-native, http-headers, http2, spdy

We have requirements to develop APIs for an application that needs to be very network efficient in terms of the bytes that pass through the network. We decided to start trying with http/2. The clients are mobile applications written in react-native.
The APIs and the applications are working very well and stable but when we started to monitor the network consumption we realized that the first call, which is the most expensive one, is performed in HTTP 1.1 without headers or body compression.

Is it possible to perform all the process in http/2 including the initial handshake?

Thanks,

GA

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP/2 specification](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#starting) lists the three ways that HTTP/2 can be negotiated:

1. Upgrading a HTTP/1.1 connection
2. Agreeing this as part of the HTTPS negotiation (using ALPN). Note HTTPS connections must use this method and not the other two.
3. Just start talking HTTP/2 (requires prior knowledge to know the sever supports HTTP/2).

I presume since you are doing the upgrade you are doing this over plaintext HTTP rather than over HTTPS? If so you can use the last method if react-native supports this, but it might be easier to just set up HTTPS on the server when this should happen automatically.

However I’d question what benefit you expect to get over this given the reasons you gave (“we realized that the first call, which is the most expensive one, is performed in HTTP 1.1 without headers or body compression.”). There may be other benefits to switching but headers and body compression are probably not them.

HTTP/2 header compression works on storing the headers from the first request in a dictionary and then referencing them in subsequent requests. So the first request will not benefit from this as the full headers are sent in that request. Well this is not quite true as it will replace common headers (e.g. `method: GET`) with references from a pre-defined dictionary of common headers, but these will not be large headers so not a huge gain.

On your other point, HTTP Body’s can be compressed equally under HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.